# How can I get my student_before_update Trigger to display my error message if EnrolledDate is in future?

Tags: mysql, triggers

```html
-- Create a trigger that will prevent  an update to a student table if EnrolledDate is in the future

USE College ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  Student_Before_Update; 

DELIMITER $$

        CREATE TRIGGER Student_Before_Update
        BEFORE UPDATE ON Student 
        FOR EACH ROW 
        
      BEGIN 
      
 IF NEW.EnrolledDate > '2016-10-18'  THEN 
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT= 'Enrolled date may not be in the future';
  END IF; 

      END $$

DELIMITER ;

UPDATE Student
SET EnrolledDate= DATE(now())
WHERE ID= 1; 

UPDATE Student
SET EnrolledDate= DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
WHERE ID=1;
```

Hello Everyone,

I am working on creating a BEFORE UPDATE trigger which should display an error message if I UPDATE a student's EnrolledDate with a future date. For example, the last inserted date in my Student record with an EnrolledDate is '2016-10-18', so any other record after that date should flag an error message saying "Enrolled Date may not be in the future." I have been literally working on this for hours, but I am not getting anyway. Can someone please help me? Here  is my code so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in MySQL directly, but there is a hack that will allow you to do that [here](http://www.brokenbuild.com/blog/2006/08/15/mysql-triggers-how-do-you-abort-an-insert-update-or-delete-with-a-trigger/):

```
IF NEW.EnrolledDate > GetDate()  THEN         
    DECLARE dummy INT;

    SELECT 
    'Your meaningful error message goes here
    INTO dummy 
        FROM mytable
      WHERE mytable.id=new.id
END IF;
```

**EDIT 1** also providing `GetDate()` instead of a hard-coded date; assuming that `EnralledDate` is, indeed, a date field

**EDIT 2** adjusting code since it is MySQL

Comment: It has an red line in MySQL editor. It says unexpected identifier. The RAISERROR

Comment: Ah... it would help if you specified that you use MySQL

Comment: @bc004346-It doesn't help me. It doesn't know what the dummy variable is. Uninitialized variable called dummy is the error message its telling me. This solution can't be the only way to solve my problem. Any other solutions. Please?